# duplicate interface declaration for class 'test_coredataAppDelegate'

Tags: objective-c, core-data

two errors suddenly fired in this piece of code 
- duplicate interface declaration for class 'test_coredataAppDelegate' 
- redefinition of 'struct test_coredataAppDelegate'

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface test_coredataAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

    ///////////////////New parts /////////////////////////
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

how to fix that please

Best regards

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- you have two interfaces with the same name.  Use Xcode's find in project menu option to find instances of `test_coredataAppDelegate`.  Then rename one of the interfaces
- somehow you have managed to import the .h file twice.  Check to make sure you always use `#import` and not `#include`.

**Edit:**

A bit more info on `#import`/`#include`:

`#include` blindly includes the file at the location of the `#include` statement.  This means that if you `#include` a file twice in your `.m` you will get two copies of the file.  Almost all traditional C `#include` files have something like the following bracketing all the content:

```
// some_file.h
#if !defined SOME_FILE_H
#define SOME_FILE_H

//  entire content of #include file

#endif
```

The above is sometimes referred to as an include guard macro.

In Objective-C, if you `#import` a file, a check is performed by the compiler to make sure it has not already been imported.  Consequently the guards are usually omitted. So if you `#include` a file  that was supposed to be `#import`ed, neither check will be done and you will sometimes get duplicate definitions.

Comment: Had somehow copied an extra version of file.  Thanks.

Comment: Did the same mistake had the same file in the project directory twice. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how to "Use Xcode's find in project menu option to find instances of  xxx". I am using Xcoder 11.3. No Project menu option...

Comment: @Yossi it's moved since 2011. The "find in project" functionality is now part of the search table in the navigation bar.

Comment: Hmmm... Didn't notice the messages are from 2011... But we are still here :)     "Navigation bar' = the Xcode/File/Edit/... menu?

Comment: @Yossi No, the pane to the left of the main editor window.

Answer (score 12):

This happen because you have a copy of that resource in your finder. It is not necessary had added it in your project. You should find in your finder the files with the same name and delete the files duplicated.

Comment: This happened to me. Why in the world would XCode vacuum in files that aren't in the project?

Answer (score 6):

In my case replacing

```
#import "Mixpanel.h"
```

to

```
#import <Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h>
```

Resolved the error

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution for this 
first copy that file 
for example video.m is giving this error 
so copy this file and delete that file and just paste it again and add that file to project again 
:)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted date model class and create new one and issue fixed.
also delete from project directory.