# Duplicate interface definition for class SBJsonBase?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, facebook-ios-sdk

I added the Facebook sdk code to my project then I got this error because I already had a json library, so I deleted the Facebook json library from my computer and from the project but I still get this error. I search the whole project for "@interface SBJsonBase" and I only get one result. How can it say it's a duplicate when I only have one interface? Is it including the file twice? Does the search not always find everything?

Comment: NOTE: My question has not been answered yet, this was an unrelated tip.Thanks Darin, I never would have noticed that.

Comment: Please refer to answer of [duplicate interface declaration for class 'test_coredataAppDeleg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180232/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-test-coredataappdelegate). Some how you #import a header file twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps? Delete your derived data and do a clean project, then try to build again

Comment: I renamed the src folder to src2 and then re-added that folder to the project and it worked. But ya that probably would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem. It was a small search, but I could solve it without creating a new project etc...
The thing was I had a Class B that was importing Class A.
Then I had a class that imported Class B and also Class A.
When I did this, these problems occured.
Eg. A SOAP webservice Class imports all the Entities that are passed over the web.

Class goToSchoolWebservice.

## import "person.h"

## import "school.h"

...

Then I had a Singleton class used for caching that had the Logged in Person and also a ref to the webservice class.

## import "person.h"

## import "goToSchoolWebservice.h"

--> this is where is went wrong!!
So watch out for these circular references. ITs not so easy to detect them!

Answer (score 0):

if your using #include instead of import then use this technique to minimize duplicates: at the begining of your interface (actually right before it) do check for a definition and if not defined then define it and proceed to define your interface.  here is an example:

```
 #ifndef __NetworkOptionsViewController__H // check if this has every been imported before
 #define __NetworkOptionsViewController__H


#import "blahblah.h"

 @interface NetworkOptionsViewController : UITableViewController

 {

NSMutableArray* somevariable1;
int somevariable2;


 }
 @end



 #endif
```

-- for me personally, i got this error though because  the file path to my class was wrong.    I checked file inspector and my class file was not defined in Classes folder even though the IDE said it was.  I deleted them and copied them over again.

Answer (score 0):

For those that still get this error, despite following header import conventions: I got this error from importing a header that had been deleted from the project. The missing header was instead found in an old backup of my project in dropbox (That I made before doing some destructive stuff in Git), and that file caused the circular import.

Answer (score -3):

I solved a similar problem by moving all the imports to the prefix header file.