# Duplicate interface definition for SUPDefaultCallbackhandler

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

[click here to see snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX9iG.png)
This is the error that we got when we tried to develop an application in xcode using objective c.We are not able to understand where the duplicate definition is happening since we are new to the technology.Please help us.

Comment: @V-Xtreme U have any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry dude .I don't have any idea about this but just check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180232/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-test-coredataappdelegate.This might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

if your using #include instead of import then use this technique to minimize duplicates: at the begining of your interface (actually right before it) do check for a definition and if not defined then define it and proceed to define your interface.  here is an example:

```
 #ifndef __NetworkOptionsViewController__H // check if this has every been imported before
 #define __NetworkOptionsViewController__H


#import "blahblah.h"

 @interface NetworkOptionsViewController : UITableViewController

 {

NSMutableArray* somevariable1;
int somevariable2;


 }
 @end



 #endif
```

-- Onto your specific trouble which i have encoutered before, i got this error because  the file path to my class was wrong.    I checked file inspector and my class file path was not defined in Classes folder yet in  the IDE it was.  I deleted them and copied them over again.