# Duplicate interface definition for class 'NSValue'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a very strange error trying to compile my project, I get an error in `NSValue.h` saying 'Duplicate interface definition for class 'NSValue' (and NSNumber).

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, I've tried clearing the module cache using:

```
rm -rf /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/*
```

I've tried removing and re-adding the Foundation framework in combination with the above, but I still get the error.

What's going on?

Comment: Probably you imported something twice or you have headers cycle. Use #import instead of #include to avoid such problems and in header files do forward declaraction with @class instead of importing other headers.

Comment: Have you read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5180324/1673400)?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski The `#import` statement (unlike the `#include` statement) guards against such errors.

Comment: @trojanfoe for multiple imports yes, but for header cycles the solution is to do "@class" forward declaration instead of #import.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski You edited your comment multiple times and I didn't keep-up.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I spotted what was causing the error: in one of my files I had

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>
```

instead of

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

(with a capital F). Fixing this solved the problem.