# Can I use a custom UIScrollView twice?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `PSCollectionView` that I have used once.
Now i want to use it again in another `ViewController` but when I begin to implement it i get `Duplicate interface definition for class 'PSCollectionView'` and `Property has a previous declaration` everywhere. I have no idea what to do.

Like this :

```
self.waterflowView = [[PSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
self.waterflowView.delegate = self; // This is for UIScrollViewDelegate
self.waterflowView.collectionViewDelegate = self;
self.waterflowView.collectionViewDataSource = self;
self.waterflowView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.waterflowView.delaysContentTouches = NO;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    self.waterflowView.numColsPortrait = 1;
    self.waterflowView.numColsLandscape = 2;
} else {
    self.waterflowView.numColsPortrait = 1;
    self.waterflowView.numColsLandscape = 2;
}

[self.mainView addSubview:waterflowView];
```

When i add this code for the second UIScrollView I want to do

```
@interface KerkoViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, PSCollectionViewDataSource, PSCollectionViewDelegate>
```

I get error in the PSCollectionView.h file in these lines:

```
@interface PSCollectionView : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *headerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *footerView;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGFloat colWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSInteger numCols;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger numColsLandscape;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger numColsPortrait;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <PSCollectionViewDelegate> collectionViewDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <PSCollectionViewDataSource> collectionViewDataSource;
```

and the import statements

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include "PSCollectionView.h"
#import "WaterflowViewCell.h"
#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"
```

Comment: How are you 'trying to using it again'?

Comment: I want to display this `PSCollectionView` in another ViewController with some other data and when declaring the delegates and whatnot i get these error

Comment: how you are using this in both controller?

Comment: paste your code here...

Comment: Show us your `.h` and `.m` `#import/#include` statements of the class that is giving you the error.

Comment: Show us your import statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicate interface declaration for class 'test\_coredataAppDelegate'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180232/duplicate-interface-declaration-for-class-test-coredataappdelegate)

Comment: change the #include to @import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `#import` directives rather than `#include` directives otherwise the compiler will try to include the header files again which would lead to the error message you're  getting.

With `#import` the compiler will handle this by itself.

Comment: Thank you, what a retarded error -_- i feel stewpid now