# Redefinition of 'xyz' Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7.1

I have recently upgraded cocoapods to 0.39.0 and xcode to 7.1.
Even after updating pods for several times, I'm constantly getting this error as shown on snapshot.

[image]

I found a same question raised [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386372/property-has-a-previous-declaration)

The accepted answer is to use 'cocoapods' which I'm already using and the other answer is to downgrade the cocoapods version to 0.38.2. Again followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/downgrading-or-installing-older-version-of-cocoapods) to downgrade cocoapods. But even after that I'm still getting the same error.

I have also tried to remove all pod files and update fresh, it didn't work out either.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the derived data and clean the project?

Comment: Yes I have done that also.

Comment: I had the same problem, deleting the whole Derived data folder and downgrading cocoapods worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `Derived Data` directory worked for me. Open Preferences of XCode and goto last tab `Locations`. Click on the marked tiny arrow:
[image]

Then I deleted this entire `Derived Data` directory. Re-running the app showed no issue.

[image]